# Is there any simple way to execute all the . drl files in the directory

Tags: java, drools, kie

I'm using Kie, I want to execute all the .drl files in a directory. is there any simpler way ??...

Folder Structure:

```
1. /drools/rules/rule_1.drl
2. /drools/rules/rule_2.drl
3. /drools/rules/rule_3.drl
4. /drools/rules/rule_4.drl
```

---

```
ResourceFactory.newFileResource(drlFile))
```

I have used the above code to load a single file to kieSession.

Expected: Is there any simple way to load all the files in a directory to kieSession

Comment: Did you try creating a `kmodule` and specify your directory so all the rules files in that package/directory will be loaded in the `ksession`. Reference: [Drools+SpringBoot](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-boot-drools-hello-world)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a kmodule.xml file in your resources folder, like this:

```
resources -> META-INF -> kmodule.xml
```

Very important to have this structure. In the META-INF folder you also need to have the following directory:

```
resources -> META-INF -> maven -> pom.properties
```

Otherwise working with the kmodule.xml file does not work.

Your definition of the kmodule.xml file would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="mypackage" packages="drools.rules">
        <ksession name="mysession" type="stateless"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

If you use packages instead of files, the container could be created in this way:

```
this.kieContainer = this.kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
```

You would then be able to to create a, for example, stateless session in this way:

```
StatelessKieSession statelessKieSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession("mysession");
```

If you need the kieBase for whatever reason, you use:

```
kieBase = statelessKieSession.getKieBase();
```

Comment: This is fine, 

can i create a new kmodule with other kbase name and package name "dynamically" in kmodule.xml, so that i can add newly created kmodule to the KieContainer.?

Comment: You only maintain one kmodule.xml in the project but you can create as many kbase within it as you need. To reuse the creation of the session as mentioned above, ideally you would wrap this creation of the session in a method that receives the session name as a parameter.